# Array of Structs with an enum member causes error when giving the array a NULL termination, but no error when not doing so

Tags: c++

I've tried searching for this, but I've not found what causes this strange behavior, there must be something I'm missing but I can't tell what it is:

The problem is the following i have the following struct:

```
struct s_log_message{
    lll level;
    const unsigned int i;
    const char *msg;
}typedef log_message;
```

and the following array of said structs:

```
const log_message logging_messages[]{
    {
        error,
        0,
        ACR "ERROR" ACS ":" "No arguments given, use -h or --help for information on how to use the program\0"
    },
    NULL
};
```

ACR and ACS are defines to change terminal color.

lll level is an enum:

```
enum log_level_list{none=0,info=1,warn=2,error=3};
typedef enum log_level_list     lll;
```

All this code is in 3 different files:

log.h:

```
#ifndef LOG
#define LOG 220

enum log_level_list{none=0,info=1,warn=2,error=3};
typedef enum log_level_list     lll;

class log{
public:
    static void                         set_log_level(lll val);
    static unsigned char        get_log_level(void);

    static void                         l(unsigned int warn_i);
private:
    log(){}

    static unsigned char        log_level;
};

#endif
```

lmg.h:

```
#ifndef     LOG_MESSAGES
#define     LOG_MESSAGES    100
#include "../lib/log.h" //included for definition of enum type lll

struct s_log_message{
    lll level;
    const unsigned int i;
    const char *msg;
}typedef log_message;

extern const log_message logging_messages[];

#endif
```

and lmg.cpp:

```
#include "../lib/col.h"         //terminal color defines
#include "../lib/lmg.h"         //header for this file
#include <cstddef>                  //included for definition of NULL

const log_message logging_messages[]{
    {
        error,
        0,
        ACR "ERROR" ACS ":" "No arguments given, use -h or --help for information on how to use the program\0"
    },
    NULL
};
```

To recap the problem is that terminating the loggin_messages[] array with NULL causes the compiler o throw the following error:

```
g++ -Wall -o DFHM ./src/main.cpp ./lib/lib.cpp ./lib/EasyBMP.cpp ./lib/dat.cpp ./lib/log.cpp ./lib/lmg.cpp
./lib/lmg.cpp:12:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘lll’ {aka ‘log_level_list’} [-fpermissive]
   12 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | long int
make: *** [makefile:14: main] Error 1
```

I'm aware that spreading so little code among so many files is counterproductive, I'm just trying to get used to doing that so that if ever i get into larger projects I'll be accustomed, and to practice of course.

Comment: To append an 'empty' log message to your array (if that's what you want to do), code it as `{}` rather than `NULL`.  Also, you don't need `\0` at the end of your string - the compiler will do that for you.

Comment: The specific thing the compiler is complaining about is the attempt to store NULL (which appears to be defined as `0L` on your system) to a member of type `log_level_list`.

Comment: The odd thing is i have another array of structs which is NULL terminated and the compiler doesn't complain there, though that struct doesn't have an enum type on it, also while i imagined the compiler would null-terminate strings for me I'd thought it prudent to explicitly terminate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is a null pointer constant.  It's intended to set *pointers* to a null, not-pointing-to-anything, value.

`logging_messages` doesn't hold pointers though.  It's an array of `log_message` objects.  It doesn't make any sense to initialize a `log_message` to `NULL`.

If you want to add an "empty" object to serve as a terminator to your array instead of storing the array's size separately, you can do that, but your type's "empty" state is up to you.  For instance `{ none, 0, nullptr }` could be your defined "empty" state.  That particular state could also be written as simply `{}`, since members that aren't given in aggregate initialization will be value-initialized.

Comment: Isn't an array of structs by default an array of pointers (with their data contiguous in memory)? I've another array of different structs (with no enum type) somewhere else, that's initialized in this exact same manner and the compiler doesn't complain, also another weird thing i just found is that defining a size for the array also removes the error, any ideas as to why?

Comment: No, an array of objects is an array of objects, not an array of pointers to objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to terminate every kind of array with NULL. In fact, strictly speaking not even `char` arrays *need* to be terminated with NULL. You can happily have non-NULL terminated arrays as long as you write your code so that you don't go beyond the end of the array.

Of course with `char` arrays there is an established convention such that many functions interpret a NULL valued `char` as the end of useful data. However that idea isn't established for any other type of array.

Or to say it a different way, NULL isn't a valid value for a `struct` (or a `class`, etc). While it is for a pointer to one, that's a completely different type. When you have an actual instance of a thing (such as a `struct`) it cannot be NULL.

Comment: While in this case there's really no reason to NULL terminate this list, I was taught that the idea is that if you ever need to iterate on the whole list without knowing it's length you can do so by iterating until you hit a NULL pointer, I was doing it as a sort of "good practice", and I've hit this strange error.